# MVCForum Max Content Length

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am using the product: MVCForum. Github is [here](https://github.com/YodasMyDad/mvcforum).

There are two places where settings exist that I know of:

- \Web.config
- \App_Data\forum.config

In the Web.Config file, I know settings can be added, I found this:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
<!--   Forum settings:   -->
<add key="FileUploadAllowedExtensions" value="jpg,jpeg,png,gif,pdf,zip" />
<add key="FileUploadMaximumFileSizeInBytes" value="5242880" />
</appSettings>
```

The problem is I do not know what Keys are avaliable?

I have tried increasing the following key with no avil:

```
<system.webServer>
<requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="**6291456**" />
</requestFiltering>
</system.webServer>
```

I don't believe this is what I need to change, as it is not the correct value: 10,000. I need to extend the post Content Length. Its currently 10000, and I get this image when posting:

[image]

There used to be a Support Forum: http://support.mvcforum.com, and it had lots of great answers, but it is gone now.

YodasMyDad did such an awesome job, I wish he still had the support forum online. I am happy to host it if he wishes?

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after a few hours of investigation. Not as easy as one may think!

In the Name Space: **MVCForum.Website**

You need to look for the ViewModel: **CreateEditTopicViewModel** and **CreateAjaxPostViewModel**

```
[StringLength(6000)]
public string Content { get; set; }
```

and

```
[StringLength(6000)]
public string PostContent { get; set; }
```

Change these String Length restrictions accordingly. Re-Build the dll's and place in the **bin** directory on your Server. I hope this helps others!